# "Problems parsing JSON" エラーが出る

Tags: api, github

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/#mark-as-read
こちらのAPIを使いたいのですが、試しにcurlで

```
curl --user username:password https://api.github.com/notifications -X PUT
```

とした所

```
// Status-code 400
{
    "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
     "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

のようなレスポンスが帰ってきました。
何かリスクエストをする時に他必要なパラメータなどありますでしょうか？
どなたかご教授いただければと思います。

何か他足りない情報ありましたらご指摘お願いします。

Comment: `-X PUT` を指定しないで実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: notificationのレスポンスが正常に帰ってきます。
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/#list-your-notifications

Comment: すみません、読み間違えていました。コマンドラインに `-d '{"last_read_at": "2015-11-03"}'` を追加します。`"2015-11-03"` の所は適宜変更して下さい。

Comment: 確認できました。optionalだと思っていたのですが必須だったみたいですね・・・ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージでjson データが必要だ、と言われていますし、api にも parameter の項目があるので、json データを渡す必要があると考えます。

```
curl --user username:password https://api.github.com/notifications -X PUT -d '{"last_read_at": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"}'
```

Comment: 確認できました。optionalだと思っていたのですが必須だったみたいですね・・・ありがとうございます